# Ember-CLI - How to dynamically add component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to add a new component dynamically using the following code:

```
var view = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{image-upload}}')
});
Ember.run(function() {
    view.appendTo(document.body);
});
```

but I get the error:

**Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.**

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Like this ? http://emberjs.com/guides/views/manually-managing-view-hierarchy/

Comment: App.ImageUploadComponent.create().appendTo($('document.body'));

Comment: @blessenm - I am using Ember-CLI, therefore there is no global App variable.

Comment: Then try importing your component into the file. it should be something like  import ImageUpload from "components/image-upload;"; The path to the component is relative to where your importing from.